# Using Pandoc to transform Markdown to Beamer Latex Code?

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

According to

http://pandoc.org/demos.html

I see the command for turning an md file into a beamer pdf file.

> pandoc -t beamer SLIDES -o example8.pdf

When I change the extension to tex instead of pdf,

> pandoc -t beamer SLIDES -o example8.tex

the body of the tex file gets produced but there is no preamble. (No \begin{document}, etc)

Is there a way to get the tex file for beamer with the headings? It's not that big of a deal, but it would be convenient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pandoc has you covered! It is set up to produce document "fragments" by default, but there's the `-s` or `--standalone` flag, which will give you a whole `.tex` file. So something like

```sh
pandoc -s -t beamer SLIDES -o example8.tex
```

should do the trick.